# Cannot create object in class PHP

Tags: php, class, oop

I try to create object in PHP class, but i get some interesting errors in IDE, like `unexpected ( token` etc. Here is my code:

```
class A {
  public $a = 1;
}

class B {
  $aa = new A(); 
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Properties can only be initialized with a fixed value (as that int). If you want it to have the value of a function or be an object, assign that in the constructor or any other method

Comment: @kingkero: Answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, you can only assign "fixed" values to properties in the class definition.

```
class A {
    public $a = 3; // will work
    public $b = "hello"; // will work
    public $c = foo(); // won't work
    public $d = new Foo(); // won't work
}
```

If you want to do so, you can use the `__construct()` method which will be called every time a new instance is created or any other method that you call.

```
class B {
    public $aa; // define visibility of $aa
    function __construct() {
        $this->aa = new A();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a constructor on class `A`

```
class A {
    function __construct() {
        $this->a = 1;
    }

    public function returnA() {
        return $this->a;
    }
}

$aa = new A();
echo $aa->returnA();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a constructor in class A and see if it works:

```
class A {
  public $a;

   function __construct()
   {
      $this->$a = 1;
   }

}

class B {
  $aa = new A(); 
}
```